# dataLabel not show on every columns in HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Please consider this Fiddle:

[http://jsfiddle.net/2ween0jt/1//](http://jsfiddle.net/2ween0jt/1/)

I wonder why dataLabel didn't show on every columns:

[image]

this is the code for `dataLabel`:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      crop: false,
      overflow: 'none',
      style: {
        fontSize: '10px'
      }
    }
  } 
},
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: it's actually due size squeze not showing in fiddle increase size by dragging output area and you will see it's there:- https://prnt.sc/h6tcm2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [data label is not shown Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755251/data-label-is-not-shown-highcharts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the labels are overlapping. You either need to add some padding/change style, or let highcharts have overlapping lables.

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      crop: false,
      overflow: 'none',
      allowOverlap: true, //add this to show the labels
      style: {
      fontSize: '10px',
      }
    }
  } 
},
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/2ween0jt/2/

**API on datalabels:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels